# Visual Studio can't find SQLProvider

Tags: visual-studio, f#, type-providers

For a recent project, I've decided to use [the fsharp sql provider](http://fsprojects.github.io/SQLProvider/) to access a MySql/MariaDb database I have.

I've installed the nuget package in VS2015, and the reference to FSharp.Data.SqlProvider is where it should be under the reference section in solution explorer, but for some reason the namespace FSharp.Data.Sql cannot be found.  Is this a known bug with SQLProvider?

Answer (score 5):

I figured it out, it was because my project was targeting .NET 4.5 where as the package was built against 4.5.1.  Changing the project build target fixed the problem.